# Maven WAR ClassNotFound Exception

Tags: java, maven, jboss, classloader

I have a simple maven WAR project deployed in JBoss. This project depends on another jar (J1) and J1 again depends on other jars J2 and J3.

So I have added J1, J2, J3 dependencies in the pom.xml of WAR and when i build, I can see all the jars in the lib folder of WAR.

When my program runs in JBoss, I get class loading exception in loading a class from J2 which is imported in J1 class.

Any ideas how can we resolve this or what could be the issue? I even tried by importing that class in my WAR classes but strangely WAR class gets loaded fine and flow moves till J1 and then again gets the same exception. If the class is not found, shouldn't I get exception in loading WAR class itself?

Update:
The class is like this:

```
    package com.zebra.jpos;

 public class Loader extends ClassLoader
 {
   private Class c;
   private Object o;
   private String name;
   public static final String version = "$Id: Loader.java,v 1.1.1.1 2006/08/03 15:05:19 qolson Exp $";

   public Loader(String n)
     throws ClassNotFoundException
   {
     this.o = null;
     this.name = n;
     try {
       this.c = loadClass(this.name, true);
     } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
       throw e;
     }
   }

   public Class theClass()
   {
     return this.c;
   }

   public Class loadClass(String name, boolean resolve) throws ClassNotFoundException
   {
     try {
       this.c = findSystemClass(name);
     } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
       throw e;
     }
     return this.c; }

   public Object NewInstance() {
     try {
       this.o = theClass().newInstance();
     } catch (InstantiationException e1) {
       return null;
     } catch (IllegalAccessException e2) {
       return null;
     } catch (Exception e3) {
       return null;
     }
     return this.o;
   }

   public static Object getInstance(String class_name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
     Loader classloader;
     try {
       classloader = new Loader(class_name);
     } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
       throw e;
     }

     if (classloader != null) {
       return classloader.NewInstance();
     }
     return null;
   }
 }
```

Comment: can you post the error trace ? (note that if J1 have a proper pom.xml then you don't need to include J2 and J3 explicitely: maven transitive dependency resolution will do it for you)

Comment: I think the issue is with ClassLoader, the class for which I am getting exception is loaded using a child ClassLoader. Is there any property of Tomcat/JBoss that doesn't allow extending classloaders?

Comment: JBoss ClassLoader is not an easy/simple topic. Here is the reference doc : https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Class+Loading+in+AS7